# How can I save many PDF files as PDF files via Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, pdf, print-to-pdf

From time to the times I need to save a PDF file (that is already present on my local disk) as a PDF file via Google Chrome (this changes some properties of the PDF).

Example:

[image]

[image]

How can I do so with 100 of PDf files?

The PDF file is already present on my local disk but I want to save print them as PDF via Chrome to remove some security on them.

Comment: Voiding author security is pure hacking. I'm not sure this fits our site rules.

Comment: @harrymc Totally legal in many (all?) cases. Do you plan to remove all print to PDF questions?

Comment: What's your case?

Comment: @harrymc I signed a few documents, which added some security features on it, and now I need to test some PDF to text converter, and this converter doesn't want any security.

Comment: For security that you yourself have placed, you then posses the digital certificate. What tool you have used for signing?

Comment: @harrymc Adobe Sign + maybe a few with DocuSign. Some documents were signed several years ago, so I likely don't have the digital certificate for all documents.